# Spring Security - No Access After Successful Authentication

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to include authentication for a web app. 
The user is successfully via the login page, however they still have no access to any of the other pages.

Initially I thought the issue has to do with Active Directory, but after switching to in memory authentication for debugging, I discovered that neither work correctly.

This is my security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("test").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

After login, I get authentication successful in the log:

```
Authentication event AuthenticationSuccessEvent: user; details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null 
Authentication event InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent: user; details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null
```

However I get redirected back to the login page, instead of to the requested resource. Manually navigating to the resource still gets me redirected back to the login page.

Is my mistake obvious, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Apparently, there were some configuration options in the application config that were somehow interfering with security context sessions.

Removing them allowed authentication to proceed as expected.